# Concatenate data in an array in C ++

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on software for processing audio in real time in C++ with Qt. I need that requirements are minimized.

Defining a temporary buffer 40ms, launching our device with a sampling frequency Fs = 8000Hz, every 320 samples entered a feature called Data Processing ().

The idea is to have a global buffer that stores the 10s last recorded, 80000 samples.
This Buffer in each iteration eliminates the initial 320 samples and looped at the end, 320 new samples. Thus the buffer is updated and the user can observe the real-time graphical representation of the recorded signal.

At first I thought of using QVector (equivalent to `std::vector` but for Qt) for this deployment, thus we reduce the process a few lines of code

```
int NUM_POINTS=320; 
DatosTemporales.erase(DatosTemporales.begin(),DatosTemporales.begin()+NUM_POINTS); 
DatosTemporales+= (DatosNuevos); // Datos Nuevos con un tamaño de NUM_POINTS
```

In each iteration we create a vector of 80000 samples in addition to free some positions so requires some processing time. An alternative for opting  was the use of * double, and iterations a loop:

```
 for(int i=0;i<80000;i++){ 
     if(i<80000-NUM_POINTS){ 
         aux=DatosTemporales[i]; 
         DatosTemporales[i+NUM_POINTS]=aux; 
     }else{ 
         DatosTemporales[i]=DatosNuevos[i-NUN_POINTS]; 
     } 
 }
```

Does fails. I think the best way is to use dynamic memory. Implementing this process by pointers. Could anyone give me some idea how to implement it?

Comment: Not enough code... And I suspect you could figure if your algorithm works by using a 10 or 20 character array , and cycling 1, 2 or 3 characters from the beginning to the end, using `memcpy` or `memmove`. Then just scale it up to 320 and 80000.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are looking for is a circular buffer.

https://www.google.com/search?q=qcircularbuffer

https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/merge_requests/60

And it looks like you only need the header file and you should be good to go.

A similar tool that is already in the Qt data set is found here:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcontiguouscache.html#details

The advantage of using a system like these presented, is that they don't need to have dynamic memory, it just needs to move the head and the tail pointers.

Hope that helps.